# Android hide listview by clicking outside of it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I want to collapse or hide the listview on click of anywhere on the screen. The code is partially working. Whenever I click in the top and bottom section of the screen listview is hidden but if I click on the main layout it has no effect. I want to hide tthe listview if user clicks anywhere on the screen. How to resolve?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".OrderBrdDataActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/brdPrescparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/brdrelative_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/app_color">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/brdnavigate"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_drawerone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Order BRD Calculator"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/brdback"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="372dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/brdrelative_1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/app_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Product"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dip"
            android:text="Value"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/brdrec"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/brdlinDetail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/brdlistView1"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/expandable_style"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:visibility="invisible"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/brdrelative_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/app_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:text="Total Order Value"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Jave code

```
parentLayout.setClickable(true);
    parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (FLAG == 1) {
                addListButton.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(addpixw, addpixh));
                lv.startAnimation(animationFlipOut);
                lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                FLAG = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. for recyclerview layout_height="wrap_content" instead of match_parent

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/brdrec"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```